# Typical to have complexType of same name in 2 XSD Files?

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I am new to JAXB and dealing with XSDs. I am using the Maven JAXB2 plugin to marshall classes from them. I got them from the provider of a web service that I need to consume, but I am not sure if they have made an error in their documentation or if I just may not be dealing with the duplication correctly.

So I have two XSD file a.xsd and b.xsd, both of which reside in the same directory.

In a.xsd I have the decleration:

```
<xs:complexType name="AttributeType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="AttributeValue" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="AttributeName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="AttributeNamespace" type="xs:string"
        use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

In b.xsd I have :

```
<xs:complexType name="AttributeType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="AttributeValue" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="AttributeName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="AttributeNamespace" type="xs:string"
        use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

The error I am getting in Maven is

```
A class/interface with the same name   "com.mycompany.voice.gcs.correspondenceservice.v1.AttributeType" is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.
```

They look identical to me and it doesn't make sense to have them duplicated. But as I said, I'm new to this stuff so I wanted to make sure that I wasn't missing something.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service provider gave me the wrong files with duplicating complex types. As a result the duplicates were failing.

Answer (score 0):

As long as these two schemas have different namespaces, it is OK. Look for the `targetNamespace` attribite of the root schema element.

If target namespace is missing or if target namespaces are the same, this might be a problem.

This looks like a "copy-paste" schema design, not a preferred modular design, but it's hard to judge without seeing the schemas.

"Copy-paste" design is not atypical but is also not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked at the files and they both have   targetNamespace defined and the uris are different. :(